# Angular 2: Signature Pad need seperate instance

Tags: angular, angular2-template, electronic-signature

I am using signature pad and i need to capture more than one signature.

below is my code. I can have 'n' number of employees. I want employee to enter in input box sign it.

when you click on submit you collect all the data. please help

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  sigUrl:any;
  @ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePad: SignaturePad;
  private signaturePadOptions: Object = { // passed through to szimek/signature_pad constructor
    'minWidth': 5,
    'canvasWidth': 200,
    'canvasHeight': 150
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.signaturePad is now available
    this.signaturePad.set('minWidth', 5); // set szimek/signature_pad options at runtime
    this.signaturePad.clear(); // invoke functions from szimek/signature_pad API
  }

  drawComplete() {
    this.sigUrl = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
    console.log("Sign: "+this.sigUrl);
  }

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Employee 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" #emp1 /></td>
    <td><signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()" #sig1></signature-pad></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employee 2</td>
    <td><input type="text" #emp2 /></td>
    <td><signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()" #sig2></signature-pad></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Clear" #clear /></td>
    <td><input type="Submit" #submit /></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>


</table>
```

Comment: What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

In your example with two instances of SignaturePad, I think you'd have to use two ViewChild references like this:

```
@ViewChild("sig1") sig1: SignaturePad;
@ViewChild("sig2") sig2: SignaturePad;
```

But with a variable number of instances you might have to investigate dynamically adding components. You can check the Angular documents here about that:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader